# Expand $\frac{1}{z-2}$ on $|z|>2$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

> Expand $\frac{1}{z-2}$ around $|z|>2$

So there is no singularity points

$$\frac{1}{(z-2)}=-\frac{1}{2-z}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{2}}=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{2^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}-\frac{z^n}{2^{n+1}}$$

but we can also write:

$$\frac{1}{(z-2)}=\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{z}}=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{z^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{z^{n+1}}$$

So which one is true? the second one as for the first we get $|\frac{z}{2}|<1\Rightarrow |z|<2$ and we are looking at $|z|>2$?

Comment: Yes the second one is correct, in the first one the series doesn't converge for $z>2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already answered your own question:
To expand
$$\frac{1}{1-q}$$
as you did in both cases, you need $|q|<1$ for the series to converge. Thus, if $|z|<2$, the first one is right, whereas for $|z|>2$, the second one is right.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to your own question is correct. But please don't write “around $|z|>2$”. What you want is the Laurent series of a function on the complement of $\overline{D(0,1)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are on the right track. The Laurent expansion of $\frac{1}{z-a}$ in $|z|>R\geq |a|$ is,
$$\frac{1}{z-a}=\frac{1}{z}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{a}{z}}=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{z^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{z^{n+1}}$$
Hence, for $|z|>R=2$,
$$\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2)}=\frac{1}{z-2}-\frac{1}{z-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n-1}{z^{n+1}}.$$